# AS3 Random Image from XML - Never Repeat

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs4, banner

I'm creating a banner ad in flash which shows 3 random images from a XML file once the pages loads. My problem is that it will occasionally repeat. I've included my code, any advice?

---

```
var pHeight:Number = 84;
var pWidth:Number = 120;


var listLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader( new URLRequest("www.example.com/example.xml") );
var picLoader:Loader = new Loader();

listLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotList);

function gotList(evt:Event):void {
    var xmlData:XML = XML(listLoader.data);
    var numImages:Number = xmlData.picture.length();
    var stImage:String = xmlData.picture[Math.floor(numImages*Math.random())].toString();

    picLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotPic);
    picLoader.load( new URLRequest(stImage) );

    listLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotList);
}

function gotPic(evt:Event):void {
    var thisBmp:Bitmap = Bitmap(evt.target.content);
    thisBmp.x = 0;
    thisBmp.y = 0;
    var thisWidth:Number = thisBmp.width;
    var thisHeight:Number = thisBmp.height;

    thisBmp.scaleX = pWidth/thisWidth;
    thisBmp.scaleY = pHeight/thisHeight;
    addChild(thisBmp);

    picLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotPic);
}
```

Comment: I only see the code loading a single image.
Do you mean that this runs once the page is loaded and is supposed to display a random image each time?

Comment: I use the code in a movieclip and I use the same movieclip 3 times. So for example the animation starts with 3 cards flipped over and then one flips and then the next flips and then the final one flips. Of those 3 I want no repeats from the xml document.

Comment: Do you want on every new loading of a page it must show next three images. How is your XML structure?

Comment: In that case, I would highly suggest moving the XML-loading code out of the movieclip. You are currently unnecessarily loading the same file multiple times. I will formulate an answer for you based on your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll want to move the loading of the XML out of the `MovieClip` into your main/document class (or if you're working on the timeline, you can put it there... I'm not condoning that behavior, I just want to be able to answer your question regardless of you method).

Once you've loaded the XML a single time, you can grab the images from there, put them into an `Array`, and do a random sort on it:

```
var images:Array = [];
for each(var imgObj:XML in xml.img){
    images.push(imgObj.toString());
}
images.sort(function(a:Object,b:Object):int{return Math.random() > .5 ? -1 : 1})
```

You will probably need to modify the code above to accommodate the format of your XML.

The next thing you'll want to do is create a public method on your `MovieClip` that will allow you to set the image for that clip:

```
function setPic(stImage:String):void {
    picLoader = new Loader();
    picLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotPic);
    picLoader.load( new URLRequest(stImage) );
    addChild(picLoader);
}
```

Finally, you can use this `setPic` method to set the image on each instance of your `MovieCilp`:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
    this["mc"+(i+1)].setPic(images[i]); 
}
```

This is assuming a certain naming convention of your `MovieClip` instances (`mc1`,`mc2`,etc)

Comment: Thank You so much for your help @Marcela. I'm still slightly confused about putting all this together. I think I understand what your saying about how it is not needed to load the xml multiple times in the movieclip when I could just do it once in the first frame. Does this look right at all? (seperated by movieclip and 1st frame)

**movieclip**

    'function setPic(stImage:String):void {
        picLoader = new Loader();
        picLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotPic);
        picLoader.load( new URLRequest(stImage) );
        addChild(picLoader);
    }'

Comment: **first frame:**

    var pHeight:Number = 84;
    var pWidth:Number = 120;
        
        
    var listLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader( new URLRequest("www.example.com/example.xml") );
    var picLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        
    var images:Array = [];
    for each(var imgObj:XML in xml.img){
    images.push(imgObj.toString());
    }
    images.sort(function(a:Object,b:Object):int{return Math.random() > .5 ? -1 : 1})
        
    for(var i:int = 0; i < images.length; i++)
    {
    this["mc"+(i+1)].setPic(images[i]); 
    }

Comment: Correct except you need to define `pHeight` and `pWidth` in the movieclip, since that's where you're using them.

Comment: Again @Marcela I thank you so much for your help, your a lifesaver. I'm getting 2 errors once I test the movie. 1120: Access of undefined property gotList which shows this line   -- listLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotList); -- and I get this error referring to undefined property xml which is -- (var imgObj:XML in xml.img){ -- I've pasted my code as it stands in pastebin at http://pastebin.com/ZHrqJyF4 . I really appreciate this

Comment: The code I gave you was a guideline to use. There were some blanks that needed to be filled with the code you already had.
You need to move your original `gotList` method out of the movieclip and into the first frame of your main timeline. Then, you need to move the image array creation into that `gotList` method. In order for the `for each` to work, you need to change it to match the format of your xml: `for each(var imgObj:XML in xmlData.picture)`